# Transform (translateY) funciona pero ocasiona parpadeo

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, table

Les traigo una cuestión que me ha quebrado la cabeza durante varios días. Estoy creando una tabla con thead fijo, ésta tiene dos rows en el thead por lo tanto no me vale mucho usar algunos ejemplos ya existentes y ya no quiero depender de jquery.

He modificado el siguiente ejemplo (JS) https://jsfiddle.net/xLwgcsag/1/ e hice que funcionara para todos los navegadores, excepto IE.

Sin embargo, hay una cuestión **en Firefox, Safari y en Edge al hacer scroll a la tabla, ésta se muestra parpadeando**.

He agregado al script los siguientes estilos:

```
transform-origin: 0 0 0; 
-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);    
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

y ninguno de ellos funciona.

Me gustaría mucho que me ayudaran con ideas para solucionarlo.